# Storing millions of 3D coordinates in MySQL - bad idea?

Tags: mysql, position, game-engine

All-

So I need to store 3D positions (x, y, z) associated with objects in a video game.

I'm curious, is this a terrible idea?  The positions are generated quite frequently, and may vary some.

I basically would ONLY like to store the position in my database if it's not within a yard of a position already stored.

I was basically selecting the existing positions for an object in the game (by object_id, object_type, continent and game_version), looping through, and calculating the distance using PHP.  If It was > 1, I would insert it.

Now that i'm at about 7 million rows (obviously not for the same object), this isn't efficient and the server I'm using is coming to a crawl.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could better store this information?  I'd prefer it be in MySQL somehow.

Here is the structure of the table:

```
object_id
object_type (like unit or game object)
x
y
z
continent (an object can be on more than one continent)
game_version (positions can vary based on the game version)
```

Later when I need to access the data, I basically only query it by object_id, object_type, continent, and game_version (so I have an index on these 4)

Thanks!
Josh

Comment: Every time there is a chance to insert a new record, you would select everything out of the database, and do the loop to see if it's within a yard of another point?

Comment: No I would select the object_id, object_type, continent and game_version... At most like 75 positions would be returned, generally.  Then I would loop through those 75.

Comment: Consider rounding your values to yards before storing them into the database. This way you could get rid of many SQL terms. This could lead into a noticeable gain of performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably objects on different continents are considered infinitely far apart.   Also you haven't disclosed the units you're using in your table. I'll assume inches (of which there are 36 in a yard).

So, before you insert a point you need to determine whether you're within a yard.  To do this you're going to need either the MySQL geo extension (which you can go read about) or separate indexes on at least your x and y columns, and maybe the z column.

Are there any points within a yard? This query will get you whether there are any points within the bounding box of +/- one yard around your new point. A 'nearby' result of one or more means you shouldn't insert the new point.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) nearby
    FROM table t
   WHERE t.x between (?xpos - 36) AND (?xpos + 36)
     AND t.y between (?ypos - 36) AND (?ypos + 36)
     AND t.z between (?zpos - 36) AND (?zpos + 36)
     AND t.continent = ?cpos
```

If you need the query to work with Cartesian distances rather than bounding boxes you can add a sum-of-squares distance computation. But I suspect bounding boxes will work just fine for your app, and be much more efficient than repeatedly fetching 75-row result sets to do proximity testing in your application.

Conceptually it wouldn't be much harder to create a stored procedure for MySQL that would conditionally insert the new row only if it met the proximity criteria.  That way you'd have a simple one-way transaction rather than server back-and-forth.

Comment: I love you, this made a WORLD of difference, seriously.  I feel pretty dumb for having not done this! It literally took about 7 minutes to create the index heh.

Comment: cool. glad it worked so well. MySQL actually does a decent job with indexes like these.

Answer (score -3):

It may be killing your server because of the continuous activity on the disk that could be fixed by having mysql work in memory, add: ENGINE = MEMORY; on your table def.

Comment: Most people would prefer their data survives a server reboot.

Comment: try using google before downvoting. The data is written to the disk periodically and obviously before shutting down.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html): "However, when the server shuts down, all rows stored in MEMORY tables are lost." That seems pretty clear-cut to me.

Comment: and as I've already told you it writes to disk..... EVERYTHING in memory on your computer is lost when it shuts down if it is not written to disk.

Comment: Can you find anything to support your position? `MEMORY` tables are temporary by nature. The documentation is very clear on this point.

Comment: Uncivil way to argue this. Anyhow i read the docs and is found nothing about Memory tables having built-in persistence of any type. So let to assume it's just for temporary data.